# Fields not transfered in workflow

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I created workflow that will send an automatic email and create case record when user create order. The email sends and a case record is created but I have problem that some fields not transferred.

For example, I tried to pass the 'Order Requested Delivery Date' field to the new case 'Description' field. The case record created but the description field is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I would check 3 things.

1) is the "Order Requested Delivery Date" populated on the source record (order)?  Sometimes field names can get mixed up easily or you can be pulling the correct field name but from the wrong table

2) What does the audit history of the created record say?  Was the field set on creation and then subsequently removed for one reason or anything?

3) Are specific fields on the target record not ever populating? Data type mismatches could be the culprit here.